# Google Cloud Logging shows each log line wrapped in quotes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

a low-impact question more out of curiosity than anything else. I am logging lines from a Java container on Kubernetes, which logs a JSON format that should be compatible with Google Cloud. The JSON format is as follows.

```
{"message":"s.s.DefaultSandboxService - Used final flags Flags(true,true,true,false,false,false,None) ","timestamp":{"seconds":1630049408,"nanos":159000000},"severity":"INFO","thread":"application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-11639"}
```

The output is shown as follows in Logs Explorer:
[image: Google Cloud log line]

Every log line in the output is surrounded with `"` quotes. Why is that? I don't see similar behavior in other containers.

Comment: Are you in log explorer or elsewhere? Where is running your container? On GKE? On a VM? On Cloud Run?

Comment: The application writing the log entry is passing a string instead of JSON.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere thank you, I updated the question - the container is running on GKE and we're looking at the logs in Log Explorer.

Comment: @JohnHanley If I understand correctly, log lines on stdout/stderr are always textual, and JSON itself is a text format. If I look at the application logs, there is no double escaping going on in the JSON message, it is valid JSON and no escaping is applied. Google correctly identifies the severity and timestamp so I'm not sure how else to log the message?